# Como implementar cadeias de certificados? qual a importância/funcionamento?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, segurança, assinatura-digital

Criei uma aplicação local no VS e ao subir no servidor a aplicação não estava com todos os recursos da aplicação local, na aplicação estou utilizando X.509 e encontrei uma diferença ao listar as CA:

```
//X509Store store = new X509Store("My");
    X509Store store = new X509Store("CA");
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
quando comecei a procurar diferenças, vii que as cadeias dos certificados que iriam ser utilizadas na aplicação não se encontravam no servidor e ao tentar conversar com o pessoal da administração desse servidor eles não souberam me explicar e nem me dar uma solução para o problema.

Alguém já chegou a trabalhar com servidor com as cadeias de certificados(ICP)? qual foi a melhor solução?

http://loja.certificadodigital.com.br/Serasa/UPLOAD/Downloads/520.pdf[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnUKl.jpg)

https://serasa.certificadodigital.com.br/instalacao/cadeia-de-certificados/

http://www.iti.gov.br/icp-brasil/certificados/188-atualizacao/4530-ac-raiz

Comment: O certificado que você usou na instalação local, ele foi criado por você mesmo ou não? Ele foi assinado por uma Autoridade Certificadora (CA), auto-assinado, ou nenhum dos dois? Por fim, sua aplicação é acessível através de um browser? Não conheço os detalhes da arquitetura que você está usando, mas no geral para usar um certificado que o browser aceite é preciso que ele seja assinado por uma CA reconhecida pelo mesmo (detalhe: a ICP-Brasil **não é**) e que tanto seu certificado quanto os certificados da CA estejam presentes (esses úitlimos você baixa da própria CA).

Comment: Isso que eu escrevi acima só vale para certificados usados na identificação de um site (https). Se o propósito desses certificados forem outros (exemplo: assinar documentos digitais, como notas fiscais), desconsidere. Posso dar uma resposta explicando em linhas gerais a cadeia de certificação, mas gostaria que desse mais detalhes de como você está usando certificados no seu sistema, pra que, e que erro está obtendo. Assim quem sabe eu consiga até propor uma solução prática pro seu caso.

Comment: O certificado utilizado localmente é da ICP, no meu caso eu utilizei o do Serasa pois estou com um smart card pertencente ao serasa. Basicamente digitei no google cadeia de certificado ICp, e instalei na maquina, é pelo browser que se acessa a aplicação. A finalidade da aplicação seria assinatura.

Comment: Não aparece nenhum erro, o sistema no server não lê o smart card eu creio que é por falta da cadeia de certificados, ao adicionar essa cadeia não irá influenciar no https? Qual a diferença?

Comment: A leitura dos certificados no Smart Card é feita por um aplicativo cliente, normalmente instalado como um plugin do navegador. Aliás, existe uma ferramenta instalada com o plugin que te permite extrair todos os certificados da cadeia.

Comment: @eduardo Esquece o que eu falei, https é uma coisa, assinatura digital é outra (um não vai interferir no outro, pois os certificados usados são diferentes). Estou no celular agora (sem internet no computador) mas assim que der explico melhor. Só esclarecendo: ICP é o mesmo que PKI em inglês, ICP-Brasil é um órgão do governo responsável pela ICP nacional, e o Serasa no caso estaria agindo como Autoridade Registradora (RA) subordinada ao ICP-Brasil (o CA). A cadeia de certificação portanto é ICP-Brasil -> Serasa -> você.

Comment: obrigado @mgibsonbr.